# How to restrict app to portrait mode only in ionic for all platforms?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm working on Ionic/Cordova, I added this to `androidManifest.xml` but this didn't work for me and app is still showing in both ways

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

How can I restrict my app to portrait mode only? I have checked on android and it doesn't work

Comment: is it working for ionic ??, coz its working for ionic 2

Answer (score 329, accepted):

If you want to restrict to portrait mode only on all devices you should add this line to the config.xml in your projects root folder.

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

After that, please rebuild the platform by typing below text in command line:

```
ionic build
```

Comment: good to see. worked for me. checked on android. thanks Vadiem

Comment: how do you restrict just one specific screen?

Comment: I haven't tested this myself, but you may get the desired result with this tutorial: http://www.gajotres.net/changing-locking-screen-orientation-in-ionic-application/

Comment: This only seems to work when you run it on a real device btw. If you run it through the Ionic View cloud app it has no effect.

Comment: Note that this answer is for Ionic 1. For Ionic 2, see my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43748328/3305145

Comment: Ok for Ionic 4.

Comment: Can not find config.xml in ionic 4.. can someone please help?

Comment: Are you using Cordova or Capacitor?

Comment: @VadiemJanssens: Cordova.

Comment: @VadiemJanssens: I can see now after following the steps mentioned in the link. Thank you.

Comment: i already have this code in my app and its working for most of android devices but its not working for Leo LE2 android mobile.

Comment: Great, works too in Quasar framework with Cordova on android

Comment: It's `"Orientation"` not `"orientation"`.

Answer (score 37):

## Ionic v2+ Update

For Ionic versions 2 and later, you will need to also install the corresponding [Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/) package for any plugin you use, including `cordova-plugin-` and `phonegap-plugin-` plugins.

1. **Install Ionic Native Plugin**

   Install Ionic Native's TypeScript module for the plugin from the [CLI](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/).

   ```
   $ ionic cordova plugin add --save cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
   $ npm install --save @ionic-native/screen-orientation
   ```

   ** Note that the `--save` command is optional and can be omitted if you do not wish to add the plugin to your `package.json` file*
2. **Import `ScreenOrientation` Plugin**

   Import plugin into your `controller`, more details available in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation/).

   ```
   import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';

   @Component({
       templateUrl: 'app.html',
       providers: [
           ScreenOrientation
       ]
   })

   constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) {
     // Your code here...
   }
   ```
3. **Do Your Thing**

   Lock and unlock the screen orientation programatically.

   ```
   // Set orientation to portrait
   this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT);

   // Disable orientation lock
   this.screenOrientation.unlock();
   ```
4. **Bonus Points**

   You can also get the current orientation.

   ```
   // Get current orientation
   console.log(this.screenOrientation.type);  // Will return landscape" or "portrait"
   ```

Comment: NOTE: you need "@ionic-native/core": "^3.6.1", because lower version causes error: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionicnativeplugin-missing-from-ionic-native-core/88019

Comment: Try adding ScreenOrientation to the list of providers

Comment: `ionic plugin` no longer seems to work.  I think it is now `ionic cordova plugin`. Such as `ionic cordova plugin add --save cordova-plugin-screen-orientation`

Comment: adding `<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />` seems to be enough for me

Comment: Is it possible that this won't work on the IonicDev App environment? I followed the instructions and the app won't lock the screen orientation.

Comment: DevApp is just running your app as a webview within the DevApp app, so some native features do not work. Try compiling and running your app directly on the device and it should work.

Answer (score 14):

According to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref/#global-preferences,

> Orientation allows you to lock orientation and prevent the interface from rotating in response to changes in orientation. Possible values are default, landscape, or portrait. Example:

`<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />`

Be aware that these values are case sensitive, it is "Orientation", not "orientation".

Comment: When you scroll up on the link you provided, it states the following: "The <preference> tag sets various options as pairs of name/value attributes. Each preference's name is *case-insensitive*. [...]."

Comment: "orientation" works for me. "Orientation" gives me white screen when running the app on actual device.

Comment: "orientation" works for me with Ionic 2 in an android device.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do something on your orientation means you want to perform any action when change your app orientation then you have to use ionic framework plugin...
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation/

If you just want to restrict your app on portrait or landscape mode then you have to just add these following line in your config.xml

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
                 OR
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Please add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the `androidManifest.xml` file as an attribute of activity tag for android.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.demo_spinner.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Comment: This is the updated answer as per the [docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/screen-orientation) -2023 April.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to add the **Cordova Screen Orientation Plugin** using

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

and then add `screen.lockOrientation('portrait');` to `.run()` method

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {

    screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
    console.log('Orientation is ' + screen.orientation);

});
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your angular `app.js` add the line `screen.lockOrientation('portrait');` like shown bellow:

an

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    // LOCK ORIENTATION TO PORTRAIT.
    screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
  });
})
```

You will also have other code in the `.run` function, but the one you are interested in is the line I wrote.
I haven't added the line `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` in my code, but you may need to add the `cordova-plugin-device-orientation`

Answer (score 2):

Using ionic 7:

If you only want to lock orientation and won't use it for dynamic functionality in your app. You don't need to install any package but just to update the configuration.

- On iOS

in `Info.plist` file edit value on key `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` and leave only `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`. Like that:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

- On Android

In `AndroidManifest.xml` update `activity` tag and add:

```
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: Hey @stanimirsp, do you know why using this approach for iOS I get this error? At least on Ionic 5:
`The "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown" orientations were provided for the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations Info.plist key in the com.moodle.aprende bundle, but you need to include all of the "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight" orientations to support iPad multitasking`

Comment: @AldoFernandoSaia, portrait mode is only for iPhone.
For iPad in Info.plist must be with all orientations. Check [this](https://snappify.com/view/31dd4e3a-ffb0-447e-9fdb-c06164ee0fd7) example

Answer (score 1):

In config.xml add the following line

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

Cordova plugin to set/lock the screen orientation in a common way for iOS, Android, WP8 and Blackberry 10. This plugin is based on an early version of Screen Orientation API so the api does not currently match the current spec.

```
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

or try this code in xml config:-

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```