# Allow screen rotation on tablets, but not phones in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I found this thread that will lock it for every device [How to restrict app to portrait mode only in ionic for all platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755208/how-to-restrict-app-to-portrait-mode-only-in-ionic-for-all-platforms) but what I am looking to do is allow screen rotation on tablets, but not phones.

I was hoping this would be something I could setup in the config.xml, but I am thinking I am going to need something more like this https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation/ and do it programmatically unless I am missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `import { Platform} from 'ionic-angular';` for check device and `import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';` for rotate your screen.

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private plt: Platform, private screen: ScreenOrientation) {
    if (this.plt.is('tablet')) {
      if (this.screen.type === 'portrait-primary') {
        this.screen.lock(this.screen.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
      }
    }
  }
```

This code with check if device is tablet and check if screen is portrait then it will automatically rotate your screen to landscape mode.